# Show Button from Form2 in Form1 C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I Have two form and both contain a button.
And I want to show button1 from Form2 in Form1 But I can't do that !!
I tried everything but no success
Can anyone please help me ??

Comment: You need to provide more information than what you have included. Please include sample code. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: If you have problem still,insert your code in your question

Answer (score 1):

**Form1**

```
public class Form1:Form
{
    public Form2 MyFrom { get; set; }
    public void From_Load ( object sender ,EventArgs e)
    {
        MyForm = new Form2();
        MyForm.Show();
    }
    public void btn_Click ( object sender ,EventArgs e)
    {
        MyForm.btn.Visible = true;
    }
}
```